# Gorm - query on one to many relation does not return required results

Tags: mysql, go, serverless, go-gorm

In relation store has many products.

I created the struct like this:

```
type Store1 struct {
    StoreSeq uint          `json:"storeSeq" gorm:"primaryKey; column:store_seq"`
    NickName string        `json:"nickName" gorm:"column:nick_name"`
    RegDate  *domain.CTime `json:"regDate" gorm:"column:reg_date"`
    Product1 []Product1    `json:"products" gorm:"foreignKey:ProductSeq"`
}

func (*Store1) TableName() string {
    return "store"
}

type Product1 struct {
    ProductSeq   uint          `json:"productSeq"`
    ProductTitle string        `json:"productTitle"`
    RegDate      *domain.CTime `json:"regDate"`
    StoreSeq     *uint         `json:"store_seq" `
}

func (*Product1) TableName() string {
    return "product"
}
```

and I queried it like this:

```
pro := new(entity.Product1)
store := new(entity.Store1) 

orm.GetData().
        Model(pro).
        Preload("Product1").
        Joins("left join store on store.store_seq = product.store_seq").
        Where("store.store_seq = ?", 1).
        Find(&store)
```

In my database table has data like this

```
STORE
1   testStore   2022-03-01 23:19:18

PRODUCT
1   1   test    2022-03-01 23:19:18
2   1   testaaa 2022-03-01 23:19:18
```

I expect

```
"storeSeq": 1,
"nickName": "",
"regDate": "2022-03-01 23:19:18",
"products": [
    {
        "productSeq": 1,
        "productTitle": "test",
        "regDate": "2022-03-01 23:19:18",
        "store_seq": 1
    },
    {
        "productSeq": 2,
        "productTitle": "testaaa",
        "regDate": "2022-03-01 23:19:18",
        "store_seq": 1
    }
]
```

but it only returns one result:

```
"storeSeq": 1,
"nickName": "",
"regDate": "2022-03-01 23:19:18",
"products": [
    {
        "productSeq": 1,
        "productTitle": "test",
        "regDate": "2022-03-01 23:19:18",
        "store_seq": 1
    }
]
```

I checked the SQL query then I found that it executes two SQL queries

```
  [1.725ms] [rows:2] SELECT `product`.`product_seq`,`product`.`product_title`,`product`.`reg_date`,`product`.`store_seq` FROM `product` WHERE `product`.`product_seq` = 1

AND

 [6.370ms] [rows:1] SELECT `product`.`product_seq`,`product`.`product_title`,`product`.`reg_date`,`product`.`store_seq` FROM `product` left join store on store.store_seq = product.store_seq WHERE store.store_seq = 1
```

I don't know why it executes the first SQL query; I want it to execute the second query only.

I have no idea and this is my firstime to use Golang with gorm with serverless framework

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I make wrong releation between product and store

store has many produts so I have to relation product1 []Product1 foriegnKey

with storeSeq but i set foriegnkey as product_seq

and i also find out that execute two queries it because of preload option.